# How to prevent sticky header with rowspan from collapsing when scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I have a table header with some of the columns being `rowspan="2"`. I also have `overflow-y` . I want the header to be sticky. But it collapses all columns that don't have `rowspan="2"` when scrolling.

I thought that having 2 rows for those columns that don't have `rowspan="2"` will be considered as if it has 2 rows but it doesn't work as intented:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table-container {
  max-height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" rowspan="2">Col1</th>
        <th scope="col" rowspan="2">Col2</th>
        <th scope="col">Col3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Col3 Sub-title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the `top: 0px` declaration. This `top: 0px` alongside the `position: sticky` means that the element should be sticky with the gap to the top off the scroll container to be `0px`. Thus, the second row `<th>` element will be sticky at the top with `0px` gap, covering the first row's `<th>`. Here  is your example with the second row's `<th>` with adjusted `top` offset:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table-container {
  max-height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: #FFF;
}

tr:nth-child(2) > th {
  top: calc(1.25em + 4px);
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" rowspan="2">Col1</th>
        <th scope="col" rowspan="2">Col2</th>
        <th scope="col">Col3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Col3 Sub-title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

However, for a more practical solution where you may have a more complicated heading structure, you could look at `sticky`ing the `<thead>` element instead:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table-container {
  max-height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" rowspan="2">Col1</th>
        <th scope="col" rowspan="2">Col2</th>
        <th scope="col">Col3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Col3 Sub-title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, it does work but now there is another issue where the content that scrolls up hides the actual borders (If you set different colors to the border you will see that the scrollable content covers it). Why? Also in your example you can see the content behind the header.